# from msrestazure.azure_active_directory import ( ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'msrestazure'

Tags: python, azure, virtual-machine, azure-python-sdk

I have written the code to list down the Azure Virtual Machines. but I am getting this error. when I try pip install msrest or pip install msrestazure. none of the commands works. It neither gives error nor starts the installation.
[image]

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "d:\FYP\FYP\AzureVms.py",
> line 1, in 
> from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials   File "d:\FYP\FYP\Azure\lib\site-packages\azure\common\credentials.py",
> line 171, in 
> raise ImportError("You need to install 'msrestazure' to use this feature") ImportError: You need to install 'msrestazure' to use this
> feature

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient

credential = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id='XXXX', secret='XXXX',tenant='XXXX')
compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(
    credential, 'XXXX')

def list_virtual_machines():
    for vm in compute_client.virtual_machines.list_all():
        print(vm.name)
```

Answer (score 2):

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'msrestazure'

In your python project, install `Pandas` library and `msrestazure` python with following command:

```
pip install msrestazure
```

After the installation of `msrestazure` python library, the above error will be solved.

---

To get/print the VM details using python code, refer this [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/virtual-machines/windows/python#get-information-about-the-vm) given practical code.